# Elasticsearch update script using python bulk update

Tags: python, performance, elasticsearch

I'm using this script to bulk update docs in my index.

I need to update a field of a doc in Elasticsearch and add the count of that doc in a list inside python code. The weight field contains the count of the doc in a dataset. The dataset needs to be updated from time to time.So the count of each document must be updated too. `hashed_ids` is a list of document ids that are in the new batch of data. the weight of matched id must be increased by the count of that id in `hashed_ids`.

For example let say a doc with `id=d1b145716ce1b04ea53d1ede9875e05a` and `weight=5` is already present in index. and also the string `d1b145716ce1b04ea53d1ede9875e05a` is repeated three times in the `hashed_ids` so the `update_with_query` query  will match the doc in database. I need to add 3 to 5 and have 8 as final `weight`.

The code below works for it but it is too slow and from time to time I get time out error.

```
hashed_ids = [hashlib.md5(doc.encode('utf-8')).hexdigest() for doc in shingles]
update_by_query_body =
{
  "query":{
    "terms": {
      "id":["id1","id2"]
    }
  },
  "script":{
    "source":"long weightToAdd = params.hashed_ids.stream().filter(idFromList -> ctx._source.id.equals(idFromList)).count(); ctx._source.weight += weightToAdd;",
    "params":{
      "hashed_ids":["id1","id1","id1","id2"]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Where is the rest of your code? Please include it.